# Expand the R formula

Tags: r

It may look like an easy question but is there any fast and robust way to expand a formula like

```
f=formula(y ~ a * b )
```

to

```
y~a+b+ab
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd try this:

```
f = y ~ a * b
reformulate(labels(terms(f)), f[[2]])
# y ~ a + b + a:b
```

It works on more complicated formulas as well, and relies on more internals. (I'm assuming you want a useful `formula` object out, so in the result `a:b` is nicer than the `ab` in the question or `a*b` in d.b's answer.)

```
f = y ~ a + b * c
reformulate(labels(terms(f)), f[[2]])
# y ~ a + b + c + b:c

f = y ~ a + (b + c + d)^2
reformulate(labels(terms(f)), f[[2]])
# y ~ a + b + c + d + b:c + b:d + c:d
```

Comment: This can be written: `reformulate(labels(terms(f)))`

Comment: Thanks for the great simplification!

Answer (score 2):

```
vec = all.vars(f)
reformulate(c(vec[2:3], paste(vec[2:3], collapse = "*")), vec[1])
#y ~ a + b + a * b
```

Comment: `collapse = ":"` *might* be more appropriate.

Comment: And with the manually entered `2:3`, I'm not sure that this qualifies as "robust"...

Comment: Perhaps `reformulate(c(vec[-1], paste(vec[-1], collapse = "*")), vec[1])`? (or `collapse=":"`)